# Anaylze twitter datas with Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Anyone else help me about how can i analyze twitter data based on 'keys' whatever i write.I found this code but this is give me an error.

```
import java.io.File
import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

/**
 * Collect at least the specified number of tweets into json text files.
 */
object Collect {
  private var numTweetsCollected = 0L
  private var partNum = 0
  private var gson = new Gson()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Process program arguments and set properties
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println("Usage: " + this.getClass.getSimpleName +
        "<outputDirectory> <numTweetsToCollect> <intervalInSeconds> <partitionsEachInterval>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val Array(outputDirectory, Utils.IntParam(numTweetsToCollect),  Utils.IntParam(intervalSecs), Utils.IntParam(partitionsEachInterval)) =
      Utils.parseCommandLineWithTwitterCredentials(args)
    val outputDir = new File(outputDirectory.toString)
    if (outputDir.exists()) {
      System.err.println("ERROR - %s already exists: delete or specify another directory".format(
        outputDirectory))
      System.exit(1)
    }
    outputDir.mkdirs()

    println("Initializing Streaming Spark Context...")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(intervalSecs))

    val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)
      .map(gson.toJson(_))

    tweetStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
      val count = rdd.count()
      if (count > 0) {
        val outputRDD = rdd.repartition(partitionsEachInterval)
        outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory + "/tweets_" + time.milliseconds.toString)
        numTweetsCollected += count
        if (numTweetsCollected > numTweetsToCollect) {
          System.exit(0)
        }
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Error is

```
object gson is not a member of package com.google
```

If you know any link about it or fix this problem can you share with me,because i want to analyze twitter datas with spark.
Thanks.:)

Comment: Can you show us your *build.sbt* file ? Maybe you are missing the gson dependency ?

Comment: my built.sbt file name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.0"
 
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.2.0"

Answer (score 1):

Like Peter pointed out, you are missing the gson dependency. So you'll need to add the following dependency to your build.sbt :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.4"
```

You can also do the following to define all the dependencies in one sequence :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.4",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.2.0"
)
```

**Bonus:** In case of other missing dependencies, you can try to search your dependency on the http://mvnrepository.com/ and if you need to find the associated jar/dependency for a given class, you can also use the [findjar website](http://www.findjar.com/index.x)

Comment: should i change my libraryDependencies or add one more row ? like  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.2.0"        libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.4"

Comment: Can you share all the librarys or how can i see.Because i am getting new error i think about that

 object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils

Comment: I can't guess the error to do that. Please show some efforts understand the solution I have provided so you can solve it when you encounter it.

Comment: It this solves your issue, you can accept the answer and up-vote so others can benefit from it.